# Passenger not starting with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

So I'm very new to Ruby on Rails, I've just started learning. I wanted to try setting up a local web server running rails with Passenger.

I've followed the instructions on https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/ruby.html

However when I run the command `bundle exec passenger start` my console returns this error:

```
C:\Users\...\...\...\...\TestAppName>bundle exec passenger start

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.22/src/ruby_supportlib/phus
ion_passenger.rb:249:in `infer_install_spec': undefined method `dir' for nil:NilClass (NoMetho
dError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.22/src/ruby_su
pportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:96:in `locate_directories'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.22/bin/passeng
er:36:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/passenger:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/passenger:23:in `<main>'
```

And then nothing happens after that, I cannot open the webserver or anything. Not really sure why this is happening as I followed the instructions really carefully.

I am on Windows 10, 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i think if you are using rails and you have passenger to your Gemfile when you typing `rails server` always choose passenger instead of webrick.

Comment: I'm really confused. When I type "rails server" it just starts a webserver which works without problem. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: It starts with webrick or with passenger?

Comment: It says webrick, but I am not really sure why I installed passenger in the first place if webrick (which is installed by default?) works just fine?

Comment: Yes webrick is installed by default. Can you try installing another server like puma to see if everything goes ok?

Comment: Well okay, I've uninstalled passenger. webrick seems to work fine, so I'm not really sure why I should be installing another webserver. I might be wrong on this, incase I am feel free to brighten me. lol Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: If you go to production you will need another server. But in development webrick is fine